# How do I read the file name and process my html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I tried to make music player with electron and jquery. What I want to do as a first step is open menu, click file and then music title to be changed. I succeeded file open menu but cannot go forward to next step.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>chplayer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>CH Music Player</h1>
    <h1 id="musictitle">[Music Title]</h1>
    <h3 id="artistname">[artist name]</h3>
    <image src="http://placehold.it/150X90" id="albumimage"/>
    <div>
        <input type="range" id="musicProgress" min="0" max="100">
    </div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button id="previousButton"></button>
          <button id="pauseButton"></button>
          <button id="nextButton"></button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="range" id="volumeProgess" min="0" max="100">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>

  </script>
</html>
```

index.html

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, dialog } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

  var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Folders',
      accelerator: 'CommandOrControl+o',
      click: function () {
        openFolderDialog()
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Info',
      click: function() {
        dialog.showMessageBox(win,{type: "none", title: "Information",
      message: "github link"},(response,checkboxChecked) => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      }
    }
  ])
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

function openFolderDialog() {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(win, {
    properties: ['openFile']
  } , filepath  => {

    if (filepath) {
      fs.writeFile('path.txt', filepath, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
      });
      scanFile(filepath)
    }
  }) 
}

function scanFile(filepath) {
  if(!filepath || filepath[0] == 'undefined') return;
  console.log(filepath[0])
  fs.readFile(filepath[0],"utf8", (err,data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    var arr = [];
    if (data.substr(-4) === '.mp3' || data.substr(-4) === '.m4a'
    || data.substr(-5) === '.webm' || data.substr(-4) === '.wav'
    || data.substr(-4) === '.aac' || data.substr(-4) === '.ogg'
    || data.substr(-5) === '.opus') {
    arr.push(data);
  }
  var objToSend = {};
    objToSend.files = arr;
    objToSend.path = filepath;

    win.webContents.send('selected-files', objToSend)
  })  
}
```

main.js

How should I read the file name from file open menu and change h1 musictitle tag?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are a few things going on here. Are you trying to allow the user to select one file or a directory of files? Your function is named "openFolderDialog" but you are specifying "openfile". See the [showOpenDialog](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) documentation for the various options. On OSX you can specify both: [`openfile, openDirectory`] but on Windows that doesn't work and `openDirectory` takes precedence.

If you want the user to select only one file at a time, then your "scanFile" function isn't needed – you can use `filters` (no period, case doesn't matter):

```
filters: [
    {name: 'Audio', extensions: ['mp3', 'ogg', 'm4a']},
  ]
```

Check out this article: [Working with HTML5 Audio in Electron](https://medium.com/@Jeff_Duke_io/working-with-html5-audio-in-electron-645b2d2202bd)

To change the H1 text, since you are already using `jquery` you could do

```
  $('#musictitle').text(sometext);
```

Comment: Thanks. Then how can I get the name of the file from dialog?

Comment: @SunBathe - see: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback